# Incoming calls not showing on lock screen

Tags: android, phone-call, lockscreen, android-phone-call

I've created an lock screen app and when I try to unlock phone, my lock screen activity is showing but the problem is when someone calls me and at the same time if lock screen  activity is showing, the incoming phone not showing.

Can anyone let me know, what's the issue?

Manifest file

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />

     <activity
                android:name=".OneActivity"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:showOnLockScreen="true"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:theme="@style/noActionBar"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
            </activity>

<receiver android:name=".utils.ReciverUnlockScreen" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="900">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.securesolution.app.lockscreen.receiver.CUSTOM_INTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Can I see your Lockscreen Activity or `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen, please see my edit, Manifest added

Comment: I need to see the `Activity` declarations in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, maybe you also you also used some `WindowFlags`?

Comment: see my edit @GiovanniTerlingen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your receiver in manifest as :

```
<receiver android:name=".utils.ReciverUnlockScreen" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```